# Почему сбрасываются стили после анимации в Angular?

Tags: анимация, angular5, angular

Анимирую строку поиска с помощью Angular animation и ngIf.

После появления input'а, когда время его входной анимации заканчивается, примененные стили сбрасываются. Почему так происходит и как это исправить?
Код примера [тут](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ug5j7?file=app%2Fexample.component.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никакие стили не сбрасываются, если вы напишите нативную анимацию через `@keyframes` вы получите тот же эффект.

Вы анимируете ширину с 0 до 608, но дефолтная ширина инпута не 608, добавьте свойство `width` инпуту, точно также как и с `border`'ом, который у вас пропадает, потому что в конечных стилях данного свойства нету:

```
.search__search-input {
    .....,
    width: 608px;
    border: solid 1px #ebebeb;
}
```

Comment: А почему не применились стили, которые я задал в анимации? Они же вроде бы по окончанию времени анимации должны применится к стилям объекта...?

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади, нет, анимация это "эдакой" сахар, который существует на протяжении какого-то времени, попробуйте проделать тоже самое без angular с `@keyframes`, анимации в angular немного сложнее, потому что они работают напрямую через js используя апи браузера (`setInterval | Promise | setTimeout`)